# Why is my display frozen?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg

I have an installation of Ubuntu Budgie that I also have KDE installed on. Recently, I created and changed an Xorg conf file so I could get it to work with my NVIDIA GPu instead of my Integrated graphics, however, now the screen freezes right after boot. I get a series of messages, but then the screen freezes. This is what it looks like.

[image]

Comment: It's a process you start, in your `~/.bashrc` or in `~/.config/autostart/`. Investigate with `sudo lsof -p3707` (`3707` is the PID of the greedy task in your picture).

Comment: @waltinator what do you mean? how do i do that from my current position?

Comment: What's unclear? What do you mean by "current position". I explained, I thought, that the task with over 21 minutes of CPU time, was one initiated by you (it's running as `razi`) as part of your `login` process, and gave you a couple of things to do. Also look at `/proc/3707/*`. Find out what "it" is, and you'll be able to stop it, or decide to live with it.

Comment: Reading this I cannot see how the comments relate to what i see in the picture. Looks odd? Based on what i see, I'd say; look for a firmware update.

Comment: @Hannu Installing a "fix" before diagnosing the problem is a Well-known Bad Idea. Don't.

Comment: The words I uttered has direct relation to what is visible above, and does NOT exclude any other action... The obvious fix is to revert the changes.